# How to add text beside legend of doughnut chart using react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I want to add some number text on the right of legend of doughnut chart using react-chartjs-2 like this image[image]
How can i achive this?

Comment: what are you getting now

Comment: @cmgchess I only have chart and legend

Comment: what is also the version

Comment: @cmgchess I'm using newest version of react-chartjs-2: 5.2.0